# Stop receiving email from Community while creating user having system administrator profile

Tags: email, customer-community

I am creating User in salesforce with profile of system administrator.
while doing this, I am getting email of login to salesforce as default email
from support@salesforce.com

but I am also getting Welcome email of my community portal as well which is not required

so can anyone tell me how to stop this welcome email while creating system administrator from salesforce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I am also getting Welcome email of my community portal as well which is not required

This is most likely because the profile on which you are setting up the User is also a member of the Community.

In order to stop email triggered from Community in this case, you have two options:

1. Stop Welcome Email from Community --> Administration --> Emails
2. Remove the profile from Community (this option though also removes access from Community for all Users on that profile)

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to temporarily disable all emails sent from SF for the duration of time when you are adding Members /Profile to the communities. You can do that using

Setup -> Email Administration -> Deliverability -> Access Level set to None

Also if you are creating Users via Apex you can set a **triggerUserEmail** as False

```
User u2 = new User(contactId=con.Id,
                    username=con.Email,
                    firstname=con.FirstName,
                    lastname=con.LastName,
                    email=con.Email,
                    communityNickname = con.LastName + '_',
                    alias = string.valueof(con.FirstName.substring(0,1) + con.LastName.substring(0,1)),
                    profileid = PROFILE_ID_FOR_COMMUNITY_USER,
                    emailencodingkey='UTF-8',
                    languagelocalekey='en_US',
                    localesidkey='en_US',
                    timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles');
Database.DMLOptions dlo = new Database.DMLOptions();
**dlo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail= false;**
Database.saveresult sr = Database.insert(u2,dlo);
```

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000005KJrIAM

Comment: I would also add a caveat here that using this option impacts ALL emails being sent out from the Org.

Comment: @JayantDas I second that :) , this should be kept in mind while using this. Setting up users is one time or little time-consuming activity if one is cautious enough it can be a good strategy.

Comment: But using NONE also restricts the internal new user email notification as well.

Comment: @JayantDas I missed that.. silly me :/